# Ant: exclude a jar from class path. I want to it to act like it does not exist

Tags: java, ant, jar, classpath

This is my first ant project and I just can't seem to wrap my mind around it. I want to effectively delete the jar and then bring it back after I run my unit tests. I think this can be simulated with the exclude command. I also think that it should be done under the `<classpath>` tag. Am I correct in my thinking? I also want this jar to still exist, I just want my build to ignore it when i run this particular target. I have tried this:

```
<junit fork="no" showoutput="false" printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="false">
     <classpath>
         <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
             <exclude name="**/*xmlparserv2.jar" />
          </fileset>
     </classpath>
</junit>
```

But to no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up moving the jar around during my tests. At the beginning, I delete it, and keep a reference at the root of my class path. Then at the end, i just copy it back: e.g.

```
<delete file="lib/xmlparserv2.jar"/>
<!--run lots of tests-->
<copy todir="lib" file="xmlparserv2.jar"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Exclude matches on the entire name, try:

```
<exclude name="**/*xmlparserv2.jar" />
```

Comment: Ahh forgot to add that. My question has been updated, but my problem still exists.

Comment: How can you tell?  Does putting the JAR into a separate folder work?

Comment: I have not tried putting in a seperate folder. And I can tell because I know the behavior when the jar is not on the classpath and when it is on the classpath, and it still reflects the behavior of it being on the classpath.